# How can I remove this screw?

Tags: screws, security, screwdriver

Any one know how to open this screw?

Tried pliers but no avail and standard box of security  screwdrivers couldnt open it.
[image]

Here are [some more photos](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx_K0TUQ8NVKX0wzdGJrdTVLMmM&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are external line head screws, and are used as anti-tamper screws in some Japanese electronics.  You can probably find a driver for them from a game console hack supplier (they're used on Gamecube, Wii, and some other game consoles).  The driver looks like this (sorry for the horrible pic):

[image]

They also come in 5 and 7 point varieties (hard to tell how many points from the picture you posted).  I've also seen them called torx inverted.

If you don't want to get a specific driver for them, you can probably get them out by clamping on the head really hard with a pair of vise-grips or use a screw extractor.  You *might* be able to find a socket that will mesh with them well enough, but that's a long shot.

Comment: Looks like possibly a watch crab or adjustable spanner (where spanner means specifically "two-pin style") wrench **might** be made to work. There's also always the option of welding a nut to them ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a screw, a couple of ideas:

1. You can use a dremel to cut a slot in the screw head and then use a normal screwdriver on it.
2. Get an old toothbrush. Head up the handle with a lighter or a heat gun. When it gets hot, press it over the screw head. Hold it until it cools. That gives you a custom screwdriver. Press hard when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a rivet, in that case you will have to cut it off or try to pry the head off.

It also looks like it has 6 tabs, you might be able to get a 6-sided socket on it and break the head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe wrench for this. If you use it "downwards" the wrench tightens itself on the screw. It is a little tricky because you have to make sure the wrench stays on the screw of course.